# How to use StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase while checking array items in another string

Tags: c#, string

Please help to find out, how to use StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase in following statements.   Here i am checking whether array elements exist in string **dummyAccount** or not.

Every thing is fine i only want to use StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.

```
private string getAccount(string dummyAccount)
{
    //e.g dummyAccount="resturant business";
    string Account = string.Empty;

    if ((new string[] { "abc", "Xyz","MD" }).Any(dummyAccount.Contains))
    {
        Account = "Unknown account";
    }
    else if ((new string[] { "shop", "hotel", "Resturant","Business"}).Any(dummyAccount.Contains))
    {
        Account = "Business";
    }
    else if ((new string[] { "school", "college" }).Any(dummyAccount.Contains))
    {
        Account = "University";
    }
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    return dummyAccount;
}
```

**e.g**
  if dummyAccount="resturant business";
then  Account = "Business";

Comment: You could cheat and do `dummyAccount.ToLower()` (make a variable outside the if to avoid 3x this)

Comment: Sure, but i not want to convert all array items to lower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works.

```
private string getAccount(string dummyAccount)
{
    //e.g dummyAccount="resturant business";
    string Account = string.Empty;

    if ((new string[] { "abc", "Xyz", "MD" }).Any(a => dummyAccount.IndexOf(a, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)>=0))
    {
        Account = "Unknown account";
    }
    else if ((new string[] { "shop", "hotel", "Resturant", "Business" }).Any(a => dummyAccount.IndexOf(a, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
    {
        Account = "Business";
    }
    else if ((new string[] { "school", "college" }).Any(a => dummyAccount.IndexOf(a, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
    {
        Account = "University";
    }
    return dummyAccount;
}
```

Comment: OP asks about dummyAccount contains array element, not equals to

Comment: Thanks for answer, But I want to check whether any array element contains in string "dummyAccount"

Comment: @SiddiqueMahsud, I have updated the answer, can you check if this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this aproach

```
if ((new string[] { "abc", "Xyz", "MD" }).Any(x => dummyAccount.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
{
    Account = "Unknown account";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
private string getAccount(string dummyAccount)
{
    //e.g dummyAccount="resturant business";
    string Account = string.Empty;

    if ((new string[] { "abc", "Xyz","MD" }).Any(s => dummyAccount.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower())))
    {
        Account = "Unknown account";
    }
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    return dummyAccount;
}
```